# Lua os.remove() folder results in 'Permission denied'

Tags: windows, lua, permission-denied

I am trying to use `os.remove()` to delete an empty folder in Windows using Lua but it just results in 'Permission Denied'. I can delete files with no problem.

However if I use `os.execute()` to call `rmdir` the folder does get deleted.

[image]

What are the limitations with `os.remove()` in a Windows environment?

Comment: My guess is, `os.remove()` can only be used on files in Windows, not folders.

Comment: Fire up your command line as Administrator. This is probably the UAC screwing you over in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`os.remove`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.remove) documentation states:

> Deletes the file (or empty directory, *on POSIX systems*) with the
>   given name. If this function fails, it returns **`nil`**, plus a
>   string describing the error and the error code.

Windows is not POSIX compliant OS, therefore; exhibiting such a behaviour.

To get POSIX compatibility in Windows 7, you have to activate the **Subsystem for UNIX-based applications (SUA / Interix)** in Windows.